# why javascript doesn't execute in polymer main file?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a main file in my polymer project.
I write javascript  code in `<script>` tag.this code should execute when an event fired.but this code doesn't execute!!!
please help me to solve this problem.
this is  my main file:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>bam</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-iconset/iron-iconset.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/av-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/communication-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/device-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/editor-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/hardware-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/image-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/maps-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/notification-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icons/social-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item-body.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-icon-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<style>
paper-toolbar.main-toolbar {
    background-color: #009688 !important;
}
paper-toolbar.drawer-toolbar {
    background-color: #80CBC4 !important;
}
paper-toolbar.drawer-toolbar h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
paper-header-panel[drawer] {
    background-color: #F5F5F5 !important;
}
/*
        paper-header-panel[main] {
            background-color: #E0E0E0 !important;
        }
        */
paper-toolbar > #topBar, paper-toolbar > #middleBar, paper-toolbar > #bottomBar {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
paper-toolbar span.title {
    text-align: center;
}
paper-toolbar > #topBar span.title {
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
paper-toolbar #tabsContent {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
paper-menu {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
paper-icon-item {
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
iron-pages paper-material {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
</style>
<style is="custom-style">
.tab-pages {
 @apply(--layout-horizontal);
 @apply(--layout-horizontal-reverse);
 @apply(--layout-wrap);
 @apply(--layout-around-justified);
}
</style>
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="fullbleed vertical layout">
<template is="dom-bind" id="site-template">
  <paper-drawer-panel right-drawer> 
    <!-- Drawer -->
    <paper-header-panel class="flex" mode="waterfall" drawer>
      <paper-toolbar class="drawer-toolbar">
        <h3 class="title">منو</h3>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div class="fit">
        <paper-menu>
          <paper-icon-item>
            <iron-icon icon="hardware:phone-iphone" item-icon></iron-icon>
            گوشی </paper-icon-item>
          <paper-icon-item>
            <iron-icon icon="hardware:tablet-mac" item-icon></iron-icon>
            تبلت </paper-icon-item>
          <paper-icon-item>
            <iron-icon icon="hardware:laptop-mac" item-icon></iron-icon>
            لپ تاپ </paper-icon-item>
        </paper-menu>
      </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
    <!-- Content -->
    <paper-header-panel class="flex" mode="waterfall" main>
      <paper-toolbar class="main-toolbar medium-tall">
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <span class="title">Tip Top Tech</span>
        <paper-tabs selected="{{tabSelect}}" class="middle fit">
          <paper-tab>محبوب ترین</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>پر بازدید ترین</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>پر فروش ترین</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab>جدید ترین</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div class="fit">
        <iron-pages class="fit" selected$="[[tabSelect]]">
          <div class="tab-pages">
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
            <paper-material class="product-item" elevation="[[pElv]]" animated></paper-material>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pages">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pages">Page 3</div>
          <div class="tab-pages">Page 4</div>
        </iron-pages>
      </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </paper-drawer-panel>
</template>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var siteTemplate = document.querySelector('#site-template');
    siteTemplate.tabSelect = 0;
    var productElevation=document.querySelector('.product-item');


//the beneath code doesn't execute
    productElevation.onmouseenter=function(){
        alert('why alert doesn't execute in polymer main file?!!');
        };


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

my polymer version is 1

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo!

Try:

```
alert("why alert doesn't execute in polymer main file?!!");
```

Comment: doesn't execute again

Comment: where are you calling your function?

Comment: I call function in script tag

Comment: Check console tell me what error you are getting you will get console in developer tool which  you can in menu of chrome

Comment: no, you are just defining the function, but you are never calling it

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseenter' of null

Comment: Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

**1** document.querySelector('.product-item') will give you only first element having class .product-item so if you want to attach event to all elements having 
class .product-item use **document.querySelectorAll('.product-item')** which will return you array of element having class .product-item

**2** loop through array and bind event

```
       var productElevation=document.querySelectorAll('.product-item');
        for(var i =0 ; i<productElevation.length; i++){
            productElevation[i].onmouseenter= yourFunction();
        }
        function yourFunction(){
            //your code
        }
```

and make sure you put your code inside window's onload event so your all polymer component will be created and will be available for DOM query.

**3** Your code will give you syntax error : missing ) after argument list.

Because it will consider 'why alert doesn' as a single string and rest of string as another argument.

To solve your problem just change your code to :

```
//using escape
 alert('why alert doesn\'t execute in polymer main file?!!');
//or
 alert("why alert doesn't execute in polymer main file?!!");
```

Comment: my problem isnt alert but my problem is that event not fired

Comment: I added the WebComponentsReady event listener to allow the delay. Also there was an issue with the function assignment to onmouseenter.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap code in

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    // your code 
};
```

the problem is solved!